# A trivial map from $f:\{0\} \to \Bbb{R}^k$ is always smooth

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X = \Bbb{R}^0 = \{0\}$ and $Y = \Bbb{R}^n$ ,prove any map from $f:X\to Y$ is smooth.

I was bit confusing how to show this map is smooth ,since it seems the definition of continuous differential need the point varies in the domain,but here point in $X$ can not vary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a strange question.

However, $\{0\}$ is a vector space (maybe not the most interesting one...). You can endow it with whatever norm. Let say the Euclidean one $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$. $(X, \Vert \cdot \Vert_2$) is a topological space. The only open subsets are $\emptyset$ and $\{0\}$ itself.

Based on that it is easy to verify (using derivative definition) that any $f$ defined on $X$ is smooth as it is constant...

Comment: What is the difference $f(x) -f(x-h)$,not such non zero $h$makes the formula well defined ? @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: The only vector of $X$... is $0$. So $x=x+h=0$ and $f(x+h)-f(x)=f(0)-f(0)=0$.

Comment: what abour quotient difference for the derivative we need non zero $h$ makes the formal defined ,this is very strange question

Comment: In fact another definition of derivative (which I prefer) is $\Vert f(x+h)-f(x)-Ax \Vert \le \epsilon \Vert x \Vert$ for all $\epsilon$. This avoids the issue you point out.